# why particle System number impact the color in three.js

Tags: three.js, particles, hsl

look I am trying to show flame in particle system .But when i change the particle num,the color get changed.[1 particle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx3Bq.png)///// [100 particles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9tzi.png)  as you can see ,the color in 100 particles are changed to yellow in the beside.this is why?
i set the color as [color: new THREE.Vector3(0.02, 1, 0.5)] which should display red  only. is it contains with the HSL color?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The change in color happens due to blending. It's the expected effect when overlaying transparent particles like in your image.